# Docker History Base Image Add:sha256hash

Tags: linux, docker, hash, dockerfile, sha256

I'm trying to better understand the `docker history` output. When I run `docker history nginx:latest` I get output that nearly matches the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/e950fa7dfcee74933b1248a7fe345bdbc176fffb/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile):

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 443/tcp 80/tcp/bin/sh -c ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log  && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62  && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y       ca-certificates nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} nginx-module-xslt nginx-module-geoip nginx-module-image-filter nginx-module-perl nginx-module-njs gettext-base  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NGINX_VERSION=1.11.9-1~jessie
/bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "docker-maint@nginx.com"
/bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:89ecb642d662ee7edbb868340551106d51336c7e589fdaca4111725ec64da957 in /
```

with three notable exceptions

1. All of the lines start with `/bin/sh -c #(nop)` except for the third line which is the `RUN` command in the Dockerfile - no big deal
2. The commands are in reverse (the last command in the Dockerfile is the first command listed with `docker history`) - also no big deal
3. This one's the kicker - The `FROM debian:jessie` line from the Dockerfile is translated to:

   `ADD file:89ecb642d662ee7edbb868340551106d51336c7e589fdaca4111725ec64da957 in /`
   `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`

It took me a little while to realize that the last two commands above (the `ADD` and `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` lines) were carried over from the base image `debian:jessie`. Once I figured that out, I thought to myself, "self, the `file:89ec...da957` must be the sha256 hash of the [rootfs.tar.xz](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/b39d31635ca26c8b1f3d982090ba8d54167c4d85/jessie/rootfs.tar.xz) included as the file system. But no, the sha256 hash of the rootfs.tar.xz is `467328e24c316fd058f086eb8eb77706f3f448ad8886d202e7c9687d30692eca`.

Herein lies my question: **Where does the hash listed in `docker history` come from? And why is it different than the actual hash of rootfs.tar.xz?**

I've thoroughly reviewed much of Docker's documentation, with no luck, including:

1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/
2. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/
3. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

The hash is consistent across all images that use `debian:jessie` as the base image. Even `docker history debian:jessie` shows the same hash:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:89ecb642d662ee7edbb868340551106d51336c7e589fdaca4111725ec64da957 in /
```

and I think you might agree, that there is only one file that could possibly have a hash in the `debian:jessie` Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

If anyone could provide some insight or point me to a resource I have yet to find, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docker brew debian image](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian) is made of intermediate containers, as described in "[Understand images, containers, and storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)".

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/images/image-layers.jpg]

See [issue 25925](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25925): each layer being stored in (for instance) `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/`.

So `ADD file:89ecb642d662ee7edbb868340551106d51336c7e589fdaca4111725ec64da95` would add all files found in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/89ecb642d662ee7edbb868340551106d51336c7e589fdaca4111725ec64da95`.

(Note: I mentioned the `(nop)` part in "[Docker missing layer IDs in output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312577/6309)")