# Build docker image without generating intermediate "none" images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I do not like to see many `none` images listed when I run `docker images -a`, even after cleaning all dangling images.

So I would like to know how to build a docker image made of several layers, but without creating intermediate images for each layer.

For example, I have pulled an image `elixir:1.6.6` which has several layers but no intermediary image.

```
$ docker history elixir:1.6.6
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
6df952b1c358        5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["iex"]                  0B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -xe  && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL="…   13.2MB
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV ELIXIR_VERSION=v1.6.6…   0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -xe  && REBAR3_DOWNLOAD_URL="…   3.49MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV REBAR3_VERSION=3.6.1     0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -xe  && REBAR_DOWNLOAD_URL="h…   209kB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV REBAR_VERSION=2.6.4      0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["erl"]                  0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -xe  && OTP_DOWNLOAD_URL="htt…   237MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV OTP_VERSION=20.3.8.2     0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   556MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   142MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   7.8MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   23.2MB
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:370028dca6e8ca9ed…   101MB
```

How can I build my image so that its history is like that of the `elixir:1.6.6` example?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Nope, that’s the way `docker build` and `docker images -a` interact.

Unless you’re really really interested, I’d suggest just not running `docker images -a`.  Ordinary maintenance commands like `docker rmi` will delete any unused intermediate layers, and you need all of the base layers to run a top-level image.  This command doesn’t really tell you anything you actually need to use Docker on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: That's the "no other solution" solution :-) From what can be read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310212/docker-missing-layer-ids-in-output), it seems that an image can be made dependent on layers instead of other images (ie., dependent on the layers in the images it was built from), but in that question it seems that the image is only made free of intermediate images when passed through a registry. I was looking to another solution (a build option?) instead of doing the trick of passing it through a (local) registry.