# Does multistage docker images have the same layers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's say I decided to make following multistage build:

```
FROM node:8.6-alpine AS build1
#some other commands
FROM node:8.5-alpine AS build2
# yet another commands
```

definitely there are some layers which will be common between build1 and build2. Will docker duplicate layers, or append somehow reference already built layers?

Comment: The interesting result of a multistage build is only the last image. In your example there would be only shared layers if the two base images share some layers.

Comment: you mean that first image will be thrown away?

Comment: More or less yes. It will still be in the build cache to speed up later builds but it will not show up in the result image. This is the whole idea behind this feature. Things needed to build the app are not necessary at run time.

Comment: As far as I know, when docker is building an image, it does it layer wise so that these layers could be reused. So, that should be the case with any `docker build` whether multistage or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next is the result of your dockerfile build on a fresh machine:

```
# docker build -t test:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM node:8.6-alpine AS build1
8.6-alpine: Pulling from library/node
88286f41530e: Pull complete
d0e8a23136b3: Pull complete
5ad5b12a980e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:60cd58a7a2bd9fec161f53f8886e451f92db06b91f4f72d9188eeea040d195eb
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:8.6-alpine
 ---> b7e15c83cdaf
Step 2/2 : FROM node:8.5-alpine AS build2
8.5-alpine: Pulling from library/node
88286f41530e: Already exists
aa0be12c5610: Pull complete
719d346e6de2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:945cf56668d3e58a3b045291564963ccde29a68da9c1483e19d8a0b06749db06
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:8.5-alpine
 ---> 7a779c246a41
Successfully built 7a779c246a41
Successfully tagged test:1
```

From the output you can see image id `88286f41530e` was reused as `Already exists`.

And `docker images` output:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                8.6-alpine          b7e15c83cdaf        13 months ago       67.2MB
node                8.5-alpine          7a779c246a41        14 months ago       67MB
```

So, the base image of first stage in the multibuild also reserve in cache.

And from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310212/docker-missing-layer-ids-in-output/35312577#35312577):

> Since Docker v1.10, generally, images and layers are no longer synonymous.
>   Instead, an image directly references one or more layers that eventually contribute to a derived container's filesystem.

So, as some image reused, the layers surely be reused.

Of course, this depends on the base images you used in multibuild, they need have something to reuse.

Anyway, I think multibuild just add some trick compared to traditional build, but layer reuse mechanism is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I believe ordinary `docker build` layer caching will apply, but there are other better answers.

```bash
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS first
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      python3
RUN echo first

FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS second
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      python3
RUN echo second
```

The rules are that you must start from the *exact* same base image (in your example nothing is shared) and you must repeat the *exact* same commands (or COPY the *exact* same file content); as soon as you stray from this path nothing is shared, including in any later identical commands.

You can [use the AS alias in later FROM directives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) so if you really want to share some base layer it's better to do it explicitly

```bash
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS base
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      python3

FROM base AS first
RUN echo first

FROM base AS second
RUN echo second
```

The more common case with a multi-stage build is to have very different "build" and "runtime" images, so this often doesn't apply.

```bash
FROM golang:1.11 AS build
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/me/myapp
COPY ./ ./
RUN go install .

FROM alpine
COPY --from=build /go/bin/myapp /usr/bin
CMD ["myapp"]
```