# How is the output of `docker history` related to the image layers shown by `docker inspect`?

Tags: docker

It is possible to use `docker history` to see how an image has been created. For example, this is the output of `docker history postgres:14.7`:

```
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
7f36d29a7b0e   7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["postgres"]             0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 5432                  0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  STOPSIGNAL SIGINT            0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:d4c2ceee202d1390…   12.5kB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/lib/postgres…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p "$PGDATA" && chown -R po…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PGDATA=/var/lib/postg…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && c…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  dpkg-divert --add --re…   58.1kB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex;   export PYTHONDONTWRITE…   253MB     
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PG_VERSION=14.7-1.pgd…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:…   0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PG_MAJOR=14              0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex;  key='B97B0AFCAA1A47F044…   3.98kB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   3.47MB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=en_US.utf8          0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  if [ -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg…   25.1MB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  savedAptMark="$(apt-ma…   4.23MB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.16        0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  groupadd -r postgres -…   329kB     
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   9.96MB    
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:60911afdacfdc216e…   80.5MB
```

Note that there is some information about the `SIZE` corresponding to the command, indicating that this information is related to the underlying layers.

Layer information can also be obtained via `docker inspect`. In this example `docker inspect postgres:14.7` yields (truncated to relevant parts):

```
[...]
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:3af14c9a24c941c626553628cf1942dcd94d40729777f2fcfbcd3b8a3dfccdd6",
                "sha256:a9fa3183c5956f8d8d6c21c29162c340c3351a823a086a0a730c63d06bdb8717",
                "sha256:3a54f275df410ffd27ea5113a3207860a85c886769c6dd44f54a79c0e8db5b7b",
                "sha256:0188104e12976c1d19e4937e273a93d5909e81f751861440f2249fcec69f8651",
                "sha256:7bde5bee9d2d48ec0f0f2d78f9b4379ed9ca0f075deff67a127f4af7477640ce",
                "sha256:ef59638c463eb0beabf5c84d58bdc08ed3ecc9f20858c1692163404953cad43e",
                "sha256:96a5e612e773551c68afff7070700162981ee61854019ee595231bce957f1b45",
                "sha256:5edf3610ca635e2df28e6fd8d927a54a58e6eff11bb3fe95fe41e2d4fef0f0a4",
                "sha256:1aad6d181250c46e526a4ddf518cc9fb4868c6226055eae047e6f6f6f3e989b1",
                "sha256:73eaa982873aff5ee387aafe50f3c2e62b84399da15bc73980dea0dfeabbfe83",
                "sha256:fa997a6fd9c40c0ab391e78740314bfaf649cd2889504d773d068ba1059626d4",
                "sha256:2ad0869ba131b490bf1fac089a1063c5199596bfdae58cbf8fdd6164a27c43ce",
                "sha256:1174b32532e42feea23de0943d1a17d441a5a99fd1a01fca9ae3ed5bdd772b00"
            ]
        },
[...]
```

I'm wondering how the two outputs are related to each other?

I've found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310212/docker-missing-layer-ids-in-output) on why the IDs are missing in the first command, but I'm still confused: Shouldn't it be possible to somehow relate the two outputs to each other? Why doesn't the number of layers match the number of operations on the image (even when subtracting zero-size operations)?